# most pythonic way to compare substrings l in list L to string S & edit S according to l in L?

Tags: python

The list `['a','a #2','a(Old)']` should become `{'a'}` because `'#'` and `'(Old)'` are to be excised and a list of duplicates isn't needed. I struggled to develop a list comprehension with a generator and settled on this since I knew it'd work and valued time more than looking good:

```
l = []
groups = ['a','a #2','a(Old)']
for i in groups:
    if ('#') in i: l.append(i[:i.index('#')].strip())
    elif ('(Old)') in i: l.append(i[:i.index('(Old)')].strip())
    else: l.append(i)
groups = set(l)
```

What's the slick way to get this result?

Comment: Why isn't readability and clarity slick enough?

Comment: `set([x[0] for x in groups])`

Comment: @jordanm better `{x[0] for x in groups}` (set comprehension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is general solution, if you want to clean elements of list `lst` from parts in `wastes`:

```
lst = ['a','a #2','a(Old)']
wastes = ['#', '(Old)']

cleaned_set = {
    min([element.split(waste)[0].strip() for waste in wastes]) 
    for element in arr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write this whole expression in a single set comprehension

```
>>> groups = ['a','a #2','a(Old)']
>>> {i.split('#')[0].split('(Old)')[0].strip() for i in groups}
{'a'}
```

This will get everything preceding a `#` and everything preceding `'(Old)'`, then trim off whitespace. The remainder is placed into a set, which only keeps unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a helper function to apply all of the splits and then use a set comprehension.

For example:

```
lst = ['a','a #2','a(Old)', 'b', 'b #', 'b(New)']
splits = {'#', '(Old)', '(New)'}

def split_all(a):
    for s in splits:
        a = a.split(s)[0]
    return a.strip()

groups = {split_all(a) for a in lst}
#{'a', 'b'}
```